# WCF oddity with simple example

Tags: wsdl, wcf-4

Ive defined a WCF Service and published the service to IIS on my Win 7 laptop.

If I don't explicitly define a namespace on the ServiceContract I get the error I've seen people discuss when I try to consume the service.

The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

If I define a Namespace it gives me NO wsdl:types defined.  I've never seen this behavior.  I do have the DataContract Attribute defined on my class and it is being used in my service contract.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have something to do With ServiceModelReg.exe on my Windows 7 laptop.  I have tried however to repair and uninstall reinstall the wcf services with that tool and it's not working.